# problem using jquery ui accordion in drupal

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal-6, accordion

I am trying to use the jquery-ui accordion functionality on a drupal page.  I have teams with multiple people in each team that I want to display.  I have a view set up that groups by team, and has contact info for each team member.  My accordion doesn't seem to be working.  I used `<?php jquery_ui_add('ui.accordion'); ?>` to import the correct js file from the jquery ui module, and it is showing up in the js file.

I was wondering if I have too many div tags and that is shomehow messing with it.  Does anyone see anything that may be affecting this?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Here is some sample code -

```
<div id="accordion">

<div>
      <h3><a href="#">Team: 1</a></h3>

     <p>

  <div class="views-field-title">
          <label class="views-label-title">
        Title:
      </label>
                <span class="field-content"><a href="/node/83">John Doe</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="views-field-field-email-value">
          <label class="views-label-field-email-value">
        Email:
      </label>
                <span class="field-content">John.Doe@email.com</span>
  </div>

  <div class="views-field-field-phone-value">
          <label class="views-label-field-phone-value">
        Phone:
      </label>
                <span class="field-content">555-555-5555</span>
  </div>

  <div class="views-field-field-extension-value">
          <label class="views-label-field-extension-value">
        Extension:
      </label>
                <span class="field-content"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="views-field-field-role-value">
          <label class="views-label-field-role-value">
        Role:
      </label>
                <span class="field-content">Team Leader</span>
  </div>
    </p>
```

and here is my jquery accordion call -

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
 });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have figured it out already, but here's a solution I wrote up a while back...

http://www.cleaver.ca/content/jquery-ui-accordion-drupal-6

There can be some incompatibilities based on the version of jQuery and jQueryUI, so this may help sort things out.  There's a link to the site where I got it workin

Answer (score 0):

First off, when troubleshoot jQuery I have found it very useful to scale down any HTML that I pass to it to be parsed.  Next, are you sure that the UI library is being called in.  Try using `drupal_add_js('/path/to/jquery.ui.js');` when you load your module.

Comment: yes - I'm sure it is being called in.  I use jquery_ui_add('ui.accordion'); ?>.  when I then look at the source for the page and open the js file, the accordian part is contained in the js file.  I would like to scale back on the html that I am passing to it, but I am trying to do this with a view, and that is basically what i have to work with.  I will see if i can pull anything out of the html and get it working that way.